# Highcharts graph disappears in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, safari

Very similar to [this](http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=16388) problem except the graph disappears in a random way.
It is working most of the time. When I use live update (using setData multiple times in every second) sometimes the graph just disappears.

I had a look at the highcharts object data with the dev console, and all data objects have null values in them.

This is issue is only appeared on Safari. Everything is up-to-date. Highcharts version: 4.1.8,
Safari: 8.0.6 (10600.6.3)
JQuery: 2.1.3

Comment: You need to create a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue before anyone can help you

Comment: This is very hard to reproduce. I've written an e-mail to Highcharts support. Since we are paying customers, they should contact us to try to figure it out. If I have any solutions or a working JSFiddle example to this I'll write it down here.

Comment: Unforutnately but without any demo there is problem to recreate and investigate issue. So please try to prepare a demo, which introduces this problem.

Comment: http://people.inf.elte.hu/sajsaai/downloads/demo_live_update_graph_bug.tar.gz